# Can the shell direct where a program places its output files?

Tags: bash, shell

Can the shell override where output files are placed? (Not the console/screen output, but files created by a program.) I have a script that currently runs a sequence of input files through a program and for each one produces a lot of different output files.

```
for i in `seq 1 24`
do 
../Bin/myprog inputfile.$i.in
done
```

Is there a way to create new directories for each run of the program and place the corresponding output files in each directory? So I would get `dir1: <output files from run 1>; dir2 <output files from run 2>` etc. I suppose one way would be to just write another script to create directories and sort all the files after the program(s) had run, but is there a more elegant way to do it?

Comment: No there is no _elegant_ way other than what you've already figured.

Comment: For each run create directory `dir$i` and place your files there.

Comment: What options does your program list in its manpage? Does it always exclusively create new files, is appending possible? If the latter is true, some symlinking might work perhaps?

Comment: Unless the program has an option to specify where the files are placed it's likely just putting them in whatever your current working directory is. Use `cd` or `pushd` to change to your desired output directory before invoking the program.

Comment: Yes, the program writes files to the current working directory and there is no option to change where files are written to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, this might be what you need, assuming that your program just dumps output into the current working directory.

```
for i in `seq 1 24`
do 
  mkdir $i
  pushd $i
  ../../Bin/myprog ../inputfile.$i.in
  popd
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to change where an existing program (e.g., `myprog`) writes its files, this is only possible if the program writes its files *relative* to the current directory.  In this case, the outer script that invokes `myprog`, can create a "destination" directory and `chdir` to it before invoking `myprog`.

If the `myprog` program writes to an *absolute* path, e.g., `/var/tmp/myprog.tmp`, the only way to override where *this* write actually goes is to place a symbolic link at the absolute path linking to the desired destination.  This will only work if the program (`myprog`) doesn't first delete an existing file before writing to it.

The third and most extreme possibility for directing absolute file path writes is to create a `chroot`'ed file system, in which the `myprog` output files will be contained, after which the outer script can copy or move them to where they are desired.

To summarize: other than changing the source, setting the working directory for relative-path output files, or `chroot`ing a filesystem for absolute-path files, there really is no "elegant" way to replace the actual output files used in a program.